# SwiftUI: WebKit toolbar buttons not doing anything

Tags: swift, swiftui, webkit

This is a web browser app for macOS made with SwiftUI and WebKit. In my address toolbar i have shortcut buttons such as refresh, go back, go forward and a shortcut link button to YouTube. but clicking on any of them nothing happens.

ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var webModel = WebStateModel()
    @State var text = ""
    
    var body: some View {
   //toolbar
            HStack{
                //Refresh Button
                 Button(action: {
                    WebView(webModel: webModel).refresh()    
                     })  {
                         Image("arrow.left.circle")
                     }
                 //Go Forward Button
                 Button{
                    WebView(webModel: webModel).goForward()

                 } label: {
                     Image("arrow.right.circle")
                     }              
                 //Youtube button
                 Button{
                    WebView(webModel: webModel).youtube()
                         } label: {
                             Image("house.circle")
                             }
            }
        VStack (spacing: 80) {
            TextField("Enter a URL", text: Binding(
                get: { text },
                set: { text = WebStateModel.stripHttps($0) } ), onCommit: {
                    webModel.updateUrl(text)
                })
            WebView(webModel: webModel) //To display the loaded web page
        }
    }
}
```

View Model of the WebView

```
class WebStateModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var url: URL? = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
    
    func updateUrl(_ str: String) {
        if let theUrl = URL(string: "https://" + WebStateModel.stripHttps(str)) {
            url = theUrl
        }
    }
    
    static func stripHttps(_ str: String) -> String {
        var txt = str.trim()
        if txt.starts(with: "https://") {
            txt = String(txt.dropFirst(8))
        }
        return txt
    }  
}
```

WebView containing the shortcut functions for the toolbar.

```
struct WebView: NSViewRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var webModel: WebStateModel

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let wkWebview = WKWebView()
        if let theUrl = webModel.url {
            let request = URLRequest(url: theUrl, cachePolicy: .returnCacheDataElseLoad)
            wkWebview.load(request)
        }
        return wkWebview
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        if let theUrl = webModel.url {
            let request = URLRequest(url: theUrl, cachePolicy: .returnCacheDataElseLoad)
            nsView.load(request)
        }
    }
func refresh() {
    let wkWebview = WKWebView()
    wkWebview.reload()
}


func goBack() {
    let wkWebview = WKWebView()
    guard wkWebview.canGoBack else { return }
    wkWebview.goBack()
}


func goForward() {
    let wkWebview = WKWebView()
    guard wkWebview.canGoForward else { return }
    wkWebview.goBack()
}

func youtube() {
    let wkWebview = WKWebView()
         wkWebview.load(URLRequest(url: (URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com")!)))
}
}
```

**EDIT i've also tried**

```
func refresh() {
        WKWebView().reload()
    }

    func goBack() {
        guard WKWebView().canGoBack else { return }
        WKWebView().goBack()
    }


    func goForward() {
        guard WKWebView().canGoForward else { return }
        WKWebView().goForward()
    }

    func youtube() {
        WKWebView().load(URLRequest(url: (URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com")!)))
    }
```

And nothing happens in the WebView when clicking any of the buttons in the toolbar.

Comment: You are creating an object each function call ```let wkWebview = WKWebView()``` which is wrong.

Comment: @swiftnoob Is the App Sandbox turned on for the app target in the Signing and Capabilities? If so (if you're not sure, the sandbox is probably enabled), have you selected the checkboxes to allow incoming and outgoing network connections? Mac Xcode projects default to turning on the app sandbox and turning off network connections. With network connections turned off, clicking the YouTube button won't display the YouTube home page in the web view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned, you are creating a new object every time you call a function.
Also you should not try to "return" a view inside the buttons. SwiftUI is
based on changing state values.

Do this instead:

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

class WebStateModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var url: URL? = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
    
    func updateUrl(_ str: String) {
        if let theUrl = URL(string: "https://" + WebStateModel.stripHttps(str)) {
            url = theUrl
        }
    }
    
    static func stripHttps(_ str: String) -> String {
        var txt = str.trim()
        if txt.starts(with: "https://") {
            txt = String(txt.dropFirst(8))
        }
        return txt
    }
}

struct WebView: NSViewRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var webModel: WebStateModel
    
    let wkWebview = WKWebView()
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        if let theUrl = webModel.url {
            let request = URLRequest(url: theUrl, cachePolicy: .returnCacheDataElseLoad)
            wkWebview.load(request)
        }
        return wkWebview
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        if let theUrl = webModel.url {
            let request = URLRequest(url: theUrl, cachePolicy: .returnCacheDataElseLoad)
            nsView.load(request)
        }
    }
    func refresh() {
        wkWebview.reload()
    }
    
    func goBack() {
        guard wkWebview.canGoBack else { return }
        wkWebview.goBack()
    }
    
    func goForward() {
        guard wkWebview.canGoForward else { return }
        wkWebview.goForward()
    }
    
    func youtube() {
        wkWebview.load(URLRequest(url: (URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com")!)))
    }
}

extension String {
    func trim() -> String {
        return self.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var webModel = WebStateModel()
    @State var text = ""
    
    @State var webView: WebView?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            //toolbar
            HStack{
                Button(action: { webView?.refresh() }) {
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise.circle")
                }
                Button(action: { webView?.goBack() }) {
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.left.circle")
                }
                Button(action: { webView?.goForward() }) {
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.right.circle")
                }
                Button(action: { webView?.youtube() }) {
                    Image(systemName: "house.circle")
                }
            }
            
            VStack (spacing: 80) {
                TextField("Enter a URL", text: Binding(
                    get: { text },
                    set: { text = WebStateModel.stripHttps($0) } ), onCommit: {
                        webModel.updateUrl(text)
                    })
                webView
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            webView = WebView(webModel: webModel)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Is it working on your end? Nothing happens when i click goBack, goForward or refresh. Clicking on the youtube button now shows "WebPageProxy::didFailLoadForFrame: frameID = 3, domain = NSURLErrorDomain, code = -999" in the console.

Comment: yes it is working very well for me. Try using the code as it is, not adding something else, not changing some functions, just copy and paste as it is. What system are you on and targeting? Also take the advice of @Mark Szymczyk.